# .NET View Other Application's Memory

Tags: c++, .net, wpf, memory, memory-management

So I have two applications that work together. One is written in native c++ using a custom memory manager. This memory manager manages a contiguous block of bytes from a start address through startAddress + size. I also have a WPF application that reads text files (which are just the bytes from the memory manager poured into a text file) and displays all sorts of statistics about it. I wanted to know if there is a way that I can view the native c++ application's memory in the WPF app in real time. So some pseudo-logic might be:

- Native application could expose, in one way or another, the start address and size of the pool
- The WPF application gets all bytes from that start address through the start address plus the size

I've explored the Process class in .NET but I didn't see anything like MemoryPool, and I think the StartAddress of that object points to the *very* beginning of the application, not the first heap allocation made.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there something special/specific about the block of memory the native code is working with? Could it be changed to work against a memory-mapped file?

Comment: You could also PInvoke `ReadProcessMemory`. I don't know a managed API that does that.

Comment: Do you need to view the entirety of the other process' memory, or do you just need to be able to share a single chunk of memory?

Comment: I only need to view a specific chunk of the native application's memory. I don't know if there is a managed equivalent of PInvoke. And unfortunately the native app can't be writing to a file because it runs in real time. I want the managed app to be "attached" to the process, sort of.

Comment: In case this is still an issue - don't be put off by the name of memory-mapped files - they can be a block of memory backed by the page file, just like any other piece of memory for your process. If you want it, here's the [unmanaged side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [managed side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267535), from which a solution could be cribbed together.

Comment: Damien: Thank you so much. I haven't implemented it yet, but reading this sounds exactly like what I'm trying to do. My only hope is that it performs well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damien_The_Unbeliever in the comments posted what inevitably was the best solution. I apologize for not posting this sooner, in case anyone else has faced this issue. The idea is to use [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to make a block of memory visible outside of your application. Essentially, you create a block of memory and give it a string name (identifier). Any other application that knows this identifier can get read that block of memory as if it were their own (assuming they're using a memory mapped file to view the memory, as it is not just intrinsically visible). The caveat is that the application reading the memory must be able to parse the memory and understand it.

I used this in creating a real-time memory viewer in C# for my engine. The engine has an underlying allocator and memory manager, which now writes to a block of memory that is also pointed to by a memory mapped file. The C# application reads this memory at a given interval and displays it in a relevant way to the user (the developer). The best part is that, because the native side doesn't have to change at all to use this implementation, this doesn't affect the performance of the application at all.